# Where are NuGet libraries in Docker containers?

Tags: asp.net, docker, nuget

I'm building an ASP .NET Core 2.1 MVC application and I need to know where the NuGet libraries get stored, because one of them depends on a file I need to copy in the NuGet library folder. From the Dockerfile made by Visual Studio I see that it's making several images for each step of the building process, but Im so confused as to where the NuGet files are on the container's file system. I can't find it using `find -iname "nuget"` either.

per request my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 53204
EXPOSE 44391

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Versandformulartool/Versandformulartool.csproj", "Versandformulartool/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Versandformulartool/Versandformulartool.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Versandformulartool"
RUN dotnet build "Versandformulartool.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Versandformulartool.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Versandformulartool.dll"]
```

Comment: I have never worked on .NET but you can always use the command ```docker exec -it container-name /bin/bash``` to bash into the running container and look for the files.

Comment: @PraveenRewar I have, and I haven't found anything.

Comment: Can you share the dockerfile here?

Comment: @PraveenRewar edited my post to include the Dockerfile